# Pass statefulset's replica count to it's pod

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-statefulset

I have a statefulset and I need to know what is the current replica count from inside the pod. To do so, I tried:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: sample-mariadb
  namespace: demo
spec:
  replicas: 3
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: REPLICAS
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: spec.replicas
```

and got this error:

> Warning  FailedCreate      4m15s (x17 over 9m43s)  statefulset-controller  create Pod sample-mariadb-0 in StatefulSet sample-mariadb failed error: Pod "sample-mariadb-0" is invalid: spec.containers[1].env[3].valueFrom.fieldRef.fieldPath: Invalid value: "spec.replicas": error converting fieldPath: field label not supported: spec.replicas

How can I get current replica count from inside the pod?

Comment: That field is not available in the downward API https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/

Answer (score 3):

You can only send the fields that are part of Pod specification. The `spec.replicas` field is part of StatefulSet specification not the underlying pod's. The `template` part of a StatefulSet is the pod specification. Hence, you are getting this error.

Comment: would have been nice to have a solution to the problem and not just description of why its not working

Answer (score 0):

I have looked for a solution, and the alternatives I could find is:

1. Setting the same environment variable

```yaml
- name: REPLICAS
  value: "3"
```

2. Or you can update the value of the replicas as template variable. Example updating it as `template.yaml`:

```yaml
replicas: ${num_replicas}
spec:
 - name: REPLICAS
   value: ${num_replicas}
```

```bash
export num_replicas=3
cat template.yaml | envsubst > dapi-stateful.yaml
```